# Using sed in bash to match a specific character as long as it is not preceded or followed by any other character

Tags: regex, bash, sed

How can I use sed to match only a lonely character (not part of a word)? For example, I want to match any instance of "a" in a file, but not match the "a" in "bag" or "contain".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed, you can require that the `a` be surrounded by word boundaries.  Use `\b` to denote [a word boundary](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Escapes).  For example:

```
$ echo 'a bag a part a.' | sed 's/\ba\b/A/g'
A bag A part A.
```

In addition to `\b`, GNU sed, among other seds, supports word-begin, `\<`, and word-end, `\>`.  For example:

```
$ echo 'a bag a part a.' | sed 's/\<a\>/A/g'
A bag A part A.
```

For purposes of defining a word boundary, a word character can be any alphanumeric character or an underline.  The boundary is where a word character is adjacent to a non-word character.

#### POSIX sed

Without the word boundary extensions, the same thing can be done with three substitution commands:

```
$ echo 'a bag a part a.' | sed -E -e 's/^a([^[:alnum:]_])/A\1/g' -e 's/^a$/A/g' -e 's/([^[:alnum:]_])a([^[:alnum:]_])/\1A\2/g'
A bag A part A.
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to figure it out for myself using the GNU solution you describe here.